# Can any counting situation that works for one side of an identity work for the other (combinatorial proof)

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

If I come up with a situation that works for one side of a combinatorial proof, does some interpretation always exist for how the other side counts that same situation?  Or is it possible that one side cannot count a situation that the other side can count, even though they are numerically equivalent?

Comment: I think you're asking whether every combinatorial identity has a bijective proof. There are identities in partition theory where it's a major advance to find a bijective proof, which suggests that whether it's always possible or not, sometimes it's very difficult.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - Disclaimer: I am no expert.  Request: Can you give an example, or a link, to what you're describing?  In particular, before the bijection was found, were the identities proven using only integers or at most rationals?  Or were they proven using e.g. calculus or complex analysis?  I ask because, in a certain sense, if you prove something using only integers / rationals, one can argue every step in the series of equations _IS_ a bijection...

Comment: @ant, they were first proved using generating functions. See, for example, https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v21i2p41 and https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/handle/2142/15597 and possibly https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316582900401

Answer (score -1):

Take for example the following identity.
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}=4\binom{2n-1}{n}-\binom{2n+1}{n}.$$
The left side has a smooth interpretation.

How to understand this interpretation from the right side?

Comment: What's the counting interpretation of the left side?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Work with $\binom{2n+1}{n}.$

Comment: Even if it is difficult to interpret, is there any way to determine whether it is actually impossible to interpret?

Comment: @Murey Tasroc No. I think we can't define this way. I think, it's just my mental retardation that I can't  interpret $\frac{\binom{2n+1}{n}}{2n+1}$ as $4\binom{2n-1}{n}-\binom{2n+1}{n}.$

Comment: I know the OP probably wants an _intuitive/clever/easy/nice_ bijection, but this identity can be proven using only $+, - , \times, /$ and integers, and as such, I would argue every step of the way is a bijection, and a series of bijection is of course also a bijection.  It's not a _nice_ bijection, but it is a bijection nonetheless...  After all, "bijective proof" IMHO does not preclude things like "multiply both sides by $n!(n+1)!$" which can be justified as a bijection.

Comment: @ant, the phrase, "bijective proof", has a time-honored accepted meaning in combinatorics, and it has nothing to do with using only the four aritmetic operations and integers.